# What does Linux's "nointremap" option do?

Tags: linux-kernel, options, interrupt

Ubuntu 12.10 alpha 2 works perfectly on my new 11" 2012 Macbook Air, but only when I boot with the "nointremap" option. Supposedly this is not good to use as a permanent solution. What exactly does this option do, and why is it "bad"?

Answer (score 2):

From [the kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
nointremap  [X86-64, Intel-IOMMU] Do not enable interrupt remapping.
            [Deprecated - use intremap=off]
```

For information about [IOMMU](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt), have a look at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU).

Comment: Yeah, I know it turns off interrupt remapping. But why is interrupt remapping normally needed and what is the problem with running without it?

Comment: @Zifre Good question. I too would like to know.

Comment: @UlrichDangel What are the implications of using nointremap?

Answer (score 0):

Update to previous failing links(*these .txt files are now .html*), found here:

[the Kernel parameters documentation,*(**intremap** parameters and all others*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=intremap%20off) .

Note: **nointremap** is deprecated.

and [IOMMU *(which has more than one entry)*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/search.html?q=iommu&check_keywords=yes&area=default#).

Many thanks to [The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.linux.org) and their vast repository.

Comment: Link only answers are not frowned upon because if the link goes down the answer is lost. Better to add the relevant part of the linked text to answers.

Comment: TBH I hadn't noticed the date ... my bad